# Want to display the color map of markers representing power transmitting nodes

Tags: python, colors, color-mapping

So basically I have markers in a plot that each transmit power in different directions and I can calculate those powers and I have their values.
This plot is basically is a big room in my case and I want to draw the color map of this room that represents the different power levels or intensities in each part of the room.

How can I do that in python?

Comment: Your question is rather vague. Do you mean to ask which libraries are available for this in Python? In that case I would suggest to simple google for: [python 3d visualization](https://www.google.com/search?q=vtk+python&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=python+3d+visualization)

Comment: I simply want to know how can I do it I don't know anything about it in python so yea libraries or piece of code that I can start with or anything pretty much that can get me on track.